# Estancamiento en actualizacion Google Play Console

Tags: android

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi aplicación ya se subio, y ya se subió también la actualización, pero se ha estancado acá desde hace ya casi 24 horas, ¿a alguien le ha pasado lo mismo?

Comment: Hola, he compartido y actualizado información de Google @RicardoMendoza

Answer (score 0):

Relacionado al proceso de mejora del ecosistema y por consecuencia de la calidad de sus aplicaciones, al subir una actualización o nueva aplicación, el proceso de revisión y aprobación puede durar hasta 3 días.

Te sugiero revises la información proporcionada en los canales de comunicación.

https://developer.android.com/newsletter/play-monthly/2019/04.html

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/04/improving-update-process-with-your.html

> Nota: Para ciertas cuentas de desarrollador, nos tomaremos más tiempo
> para revisar minuciosamente sus aplicaciones para ayudar a proteger
> mejor a los usuarios. **Recibirá una notificación en el Panel de control
> de su aplicación acerca de cuánto tiempo debería llevar esto.
> Recomendamos que ajuste su planificación para incluir un período de
> amortiguación de al menos tres días entre el envío de su aplicación y
> la puesta en marcha.**

---

**Actualización:**
Revisando sobre este tema, encontré que al parecer, el proceso de revisión es más minucioso y por consecuencia más largo pero para todas las aplicaciones (espero no sea así ya que tenemos un deadline el lunes para tener actualizaciones en producción :-P).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Todas las aplicaciones nuevas reciben el banner "tomaremos más
> tiempo". "Nos estamos tomando más tiempo para revisar minuciosamente
> cada aplicación". Planifique por lo menos tres días entre el envío de
> su aplicación y la puesta en marcha. Somos desarrolladores
> profesionales y definitivamente podemos planificar con unos días de
> anticipación, pero eso plantea otro problema mayor.

https://www.choiceofgames.com/2019/08/google-warns-developers-that-all-new-apps-require-three-days-for-approval/

### Actualización: información oficial de Google

> Si bien la mayoría de las Publishing Reviews de las apps seguirán
> tomando unas horas, podría extenderse más en algunos casos, por esta
> razón quisiera compartir algunas recomendaciones:
>
> - Subir su nuevo .APK a la consola por lo menos unos 3 o 5 días
>   antes del día de publicación deseado usando la funcionalidad de [Timed
>   Publishing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334282?hl=en).  Ejemplo: si se requiere que  la nueva versión se encuentre
>   disponible el día viernes, se debe subir desde el día el lunes o martes
>   anterior con esta funcionalidad, esto provocará que la aplicación esté ya visible
>   para los equipos de "Review" y se pueda contar con el review en tiempo y de
>   manera anticipada
> - De esta forma, en cuanto la app haya sido revisada por nuestro equipo, el botón de
>   publicación a producción se encenderá, inclusive podría ocurrir antes
>   del Día "D" es decir, en el ejemplo citado, podría ser antes del día viernes, para
>   que ustedes puedan aplicarlo cuando quieran.
> - Evitar realizar modificaciones, tales como modificar la lista de distribución de
>   países, cambio de versión de Build, etc. Ya que esto reiniciara el proceso de revisión, se recomienda no realizar ninguna modificación.